# Unable to securely remove: upgrade about libssl-doc

Tags: apt

```
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
   libssl-doc
 The following packages have been kept back:
   nodejs nodejs-dev
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 1459 kB disk space will be freed.
 (Reading database ... 27911 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing libssl-doc ...
 dpkg: error processing libssl-doc (--remove):
  unable to securely remove '/usr/share/man/man3/SSL_set_session_id_context.3ssl.gz.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
 No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  libssl-doc
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

While useing `apt-get upgrade` I got this ERROR message?
I want to fix it but don't know how to do.
Does anyone know could help me to pass this issue? ><

Answer (score 0):

Me again!
Finally find the answer!
I rename the directory of `/usr/share/man/man3` to `/usr/share/man/man3.original`.
And `apt-get upgrade` again.
This problem are magically solved!!!!